# how to use loop in awk

Tags: linux, unix, awk

I use the following command to extract 2nd column from `table1.txt` and get output as `output1.txt`

```
awk '{ print $2 }' table.txt > output.txt
```

How to use loop for five files (`table.txt`, `abc.txt`, `pqr.txt`, `skt.txt`, `mkt.txt`) to extract 2nd column in respective output files (`out_table.txt`, `out_abc.txt`, `out_pqr.txt`, `out_skt.txt`, `out_mkt.txt`) ?

Answer (score 4):

you don't need to write a loop in awk. You could use the build-in variable `FILENAME`:

```
awk '{print $2 > "out_"FILENAME".txt"}' table.txt abc.txt pqr.txt skt.txt mkt.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `FILENAME` variable to use the corresponding output file name to the input one:

```
awk '{ print $2 > "out_" FILENAME }' *.txt
```